# indices of unique elements of vector in Julia

Tags: julia

How to get indexes of unique elements of a vector?

For instance if you have a vector `v = [1,2,1,3,5,3]`, the unique elements are `[1,2,3,5]`  (output of `unique`) and their indexes are `ind = [1,2,4,5]`. What function allows me to compute `ind` so that `v[ind] = unique(v)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a solution for Julia 0.7:

```
findfirst.(isequal.(unique(x)), [x])
```

or similar working under Julia 0.6.3 and Julia 0.7:

```
findfirst.(map(a -> (y -> isequal(a, y)), unique(x)), [x])
```

and a shorter version (but it will not work under Julia 0.7):

```
findfirst.([x], unique(x))
```

It will probably not be the fastest.

If you need speed you can write something like (should work both under Julia 0.7 and 0.6.3):

```
function uniqueidx(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T
    uniqueset = Set{T}()
    ex = eachindex(x)
    idxs = Vector{eltype(ex)}()
    for i in ex
        xi = x[i]
        if !(xi in uniqueset)
            push!(idxs, i)
            push!(uniqueset, xi)
        end
    end
    idxs
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Another suggestion is

```
unique(i -> x[i], 1:length(x))
```

which is about as fast as the function in the accepted answer (in Julia 1.1), but a bit briefer.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about finding the first index for each unique element, then you can use a combination of the `unique` and `indexin` functions:

```
julia> indexin(unique(v), v)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 2
 6
 5
```

Which gets one index for each unique element of `v` in `v`. These are all in base and works in 0.6. This is about 2.5 times slower than @Bogumil's function, but it's a simple alternative.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer too! I will go with the function definition of `uniqueidx` for now in my scripts. But for interactive use, the `indexin` function is very convenient.

Comment: In Julia 0.7 `indexin` returns the index of the first match (rather than the last as in 0.6).

Answer (score 5):

A mix between [mattswon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57870921/3565696) and [Bogumił Kamiński](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900113/3565696) answers (thanks !):

```
uniqueidx(v) = unique(i -> v[i], eachindex(v))
```

[`eachindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachindex) allows to [work with any kind of array](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Iteration), even views.

```
julia> v = [1,2,1,3,5,3];

julia> uniqueidx(v)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 4
 5

julia> v2 = reshape(v, 2, 3)
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  5
 2  3  3

julia> subv2 = view(v2, 1:2, 1:2)
2×2 view(::Matrix{Int64}, 1:2, 1:2) with eltype Int64:
 1  1
 2  3

julia> uniqueidx(subv2)
3-element Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1)
 CartesianIndex(2, 1)
 CartesianIndex(2, 2)
```