# Julia function to return non-unique elements of an array

Tags: julia

Julia base has the `unique` function that returns a vector containing only the unique elements of an array (or any iterable). I was looking for a `nonunique` function to return an array containing all the elements that appear at least twice in its input. As far as I can tell Julia does not have such a function, which I found a bit surprising.

My first attempt was as follows:

```
function nonunique(x::AbstractArray)
    uniqueindexes = indexin(unique(x),x)
    nonuniqueindexes = setdiff(1:length(x),uniqueindexes)
    unique(x[nonuniqueindexes])
end
```

But inspired by [Bogumił Kamiński's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269567/bogumi%C5%82-kami%C5%84ski) answer to [indices of unique elements of vector in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899973/indices-of-unique-elements-of-vector-in-julia) I wrote a second version:

```
function nonunique(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T
    uniqueset = Set{T}()
    duplicatedset = Set{T}()
    duplicatedvector = Vector{T}()
    for i in x
        if(i in uniqueset)
            if !(i in duplicatedset)
                push!(duplicatedset, i)
                push!(duplicatedvector, i)
            end
        else
            push!(uniqueset, i)
        end
    end
    duplicatedvector
end
```

In my tests, this version is about 4 times faster. It has the nice property that the return is ordered in the order that the second (first repeat) of each set of equivalent elements originally appear. I believe that `in` is faster when checking for membership of a `Set` than an `Array`, which accounts for having the two variables `duplicatedset` and `duplicatedvector`.

Is it really necessary for me to "roll my own" `nonunique` function and can the second version be improved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get higher performance by sorting the list and then searching for duplicates:

```
function nonunique2(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T
    xs = sort(x)
    duplicatedvector = T[]
    for i=2:length(xs)
        if (isequal(xs[i],xs[i-1]) && (length(duplicatedvector)==0 || !isequal(duplicatedvector[end], xs[i])))
            push!(duplicatedvector,xs[i])
        end
    end
    duplicatedvector
end
```

Here are sample results:

```
julia> x = rand(1:1000,1000);

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> nn = @btime nonunique($x);
  42.240 μs (39 allocations: 71.23 KiB)

julia> nn2s = @btime nonunique2($x);
  26.453 μs (10 allocations: 16.33 KiB)

julia> sort(nn) == sort(nn2s)
true
```

It will be much better if you can do in-place sorting:

```
function nonunique2!(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T
    sort!(x)
    duplicatedvector = T[]
    for i=2:length(x)
        if (isequal(x[i],x[i-1]) && (length(duplicatedvector)==0 || !isequal(duplicatedvector[end], x[i])))
            push!(duplicatedvector,x[i])
        end
    end
    duplicatedvector
end
```

Here are the results (the same data)

```
julia> nn2 = @btime nonunique2!($x)
  9.813 μs (9 allocations: 8.39 KiB)

julia> sort(nn) == sort(nns)
true
```

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw. I adopted your approach, but to make the function work when `x` has more than one dimension, I amended it to set `xs = sort(vec(x))`

Comment: `vec` does not create a copy if `x` is already an `AbstractVector`. As an additional note in this accepted answer it would be probably better to replace `==` and `!=` by `isequal` comparisons as now the function is inconsistent with `unique`. You can see it when you run both function a vector like `[0.0, -0.0]` or `[1, missing]`.

Comment: `vec` does not copy if `x` is an `AbstractArray` of any dimension.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard OK you are right,I will edit my comments.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the answer above, as its limitation is that the type `T` must be sortable and it is not order-preserving I have two possible solutions.

Here is another non-order preserving solution that uses StatsBase.jl. It can be faster than the sorting solution or slower depending on the density of the duplicates (also it does more work, but in some applications this information might be useful):

```
nonunique3(x) = [k for (k, v) in countmap(x) if v > 1]
```

If you want to speed up the order preserving approach you could do something like:

```
function nonunique4(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T
    status = Dict{T, Bool}()
    duplicatedvector = Vector{T}()
    for i in x
        if haskey(status, i)
            if status[i]
                push!(duplicatedvector, i)
                status[i] = false
            end
        else
            status[i] = true
        end
    end
    duplicatedvector
end
```

In general benchmarking them is tricky as performance will depend on:

- density of duplicates and over double duplicates in `x`
- the size of type `T` (e.g. if it were a very large immutable type things might change vs. standard situation)

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer (excellent answers are above) but a comment that the original implementation can be cleaned a little to:

```
function nonunique1(x::AbstractArray{T}) where T
    uniqueset = Set{T}()
    duplicatedset = Set{T}()
    for i in x
        if(i in uniqueset)
            push!(duplicatedset, i)
        else
            push!(uniqueset, i)
        end
    end
    collect(duplicatedset)
end
```

i.e. you don't need to check for existence before pushing to a set, and you don't need to fill a vector and set separately. It's still not as fast as the sorting implementation.

Comment: Przemyslaw's and Bogumil's answers take a different (better) approach to mine. Your answer improves on the approach I took. As a Julia learner it's nice to have both types of answer.